# Silex, how to translate login error messages?

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

How to translate security error messages like 'Bad credentials' in Silex?

Currently I show login form using this code from Silex docs https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/security.html:

```
    $app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('login.twig', array(
            'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
            'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
        ));
    });
```

twig:

```
{{ error }}
```

But looks like `$app['security.last_error']` is just a string, so I can't get its key for translation like this `{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}`.

This http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/form_login_setup.html suggests to use `$this->get('security.authentication_utils')->getLastAuthenticationError()` but looks like it's not available in Silex?

Comment: I've tried to fix this problem in Silex in https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/pull/1629 If you can, please check it out!

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but I am simply using `Bad credentials` as a key in my array with translations.